# How Insert data to child table in different schema using trigger function and auto updates for these child tables

Tags: trigger, partitioning, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to insert data to the child tables from different schema i.e parent table and trigger function were in schema 1 and child tables were in schema 2. It throws me an error while I am doing this. Child is not referenced to parent table from schema2.
Error is Child_test_topic does not exist. Do I need to place the trigger in child schema? And how auto insertion works in this case when new data populated in parent table?

Parent table schema - PUBLIC

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.topics_test1
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  topic character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  value character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  has_synonyms boolean DEFAULT false,
  searchable boolean,
  CONSTRAINT topics_pk11 PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT topics_pk_test_21 UNIQUE (topic, value)

)
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Child table moved to different schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE child_test_topic (
CONSTRAINT pk_pk11 PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT ck_ck11 CHECK ( topic = 'ingredient' )
) INHERITS (topics_test1);
CREATE INDEX idx_ing ON child_test_topic (topic);

ALTER TABLE child_test_topic SET SCHEMA postgres_partition_tables;
```

Trigger function and trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_test_schemapropagation() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF ( NEW.topic = 'ingredient' ) THEN
INSERT INTO child_test_topic VALUES (NEW.*);
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_topic_trigger1
BEFORE INSERT ON public.topics_test1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.fn_test_schemapropagation();
```

Insert statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.topics_test1(id, topic, value, has_synonyms, searchable) select * from topics where topic = 'ingredient';
```

Comment: If you really need partitioning, the best thing you could do is to upgrade to Postgres 11 to make use of all the new features and way better performance introduced by [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

Comment: Thank you but i am using cloudSQL in GCP - maximum version they have is 9.6. That's why  I am struggling in this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there anyother way to achieve this in 9.6?